# SWIG Python to C++: TypeError trying to set struct member of type map<string, int>

Tags: c++, python, dictionary, swig

SWIG seems to be generating incorrect bindings for converting a struct field of type map, resulting in a TypeError trying to set the map field to a python dictionary. Is there an error I am missing? an unsupported use-case? a bug in SWIG?

First the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\use_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    struct.data = { 'A':1, 'B':2 }
  File "C:\Users\kmahan\Projects\SwigTest\test.py", line 150, in <lambda>
    __setattr__ = lambda self, name, value: _swig_setattr(self, MyStruct, name, value)
  File "C:\Users\kmahan\Projects\SwigTest\test.py", line 49, in _swig_setattr
    return _swig_setattr_nondynamic(self,class_type,name,value,0)
  File "C:\Users\kmahan\Projects\SwigTest\test.py", line 42, in _swig_setattr_nondynamic
    if method: return method(self,value)
TypeError: in method 'MyStruct_data_set', argument 2 of type 'std::map< std::string,unsigned int,std::less< std::string >,std::allocator< std::pair< std::string const,unsigned int > > > *'
```

And here is my test case:

**test.i**

```
%module test

%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_map.i"

namespace std {
    %template(StringIntMap) map<string, unsigned int>;
}

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"
```

**test.h**

```
#ifndef _TEST_H_
#define _TEST_H_

#include <string>
#include <map>

struct MyStruct 
{
    std::map<std::string, unsigned int> data;
};

#endif //_TEST_H_
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
```

**run_test.py**

```
import test

struct = test.MyStruct()
struct.data = { 'A':1, 'B':2 }

print struct.data
```

I build test_wrapper.cpp with swig -python -c++ -o test_wrapper.cpp test.i, compile everything else, and run run_test.py.

As a workaround I can explicitly define a setter instead (
`void setData(const map<string, unsigned int>& data)`
) which generates different conversion code -- it goes through traits_asptr instead of SWIG_ConvertPtr -- and seems to work but is not very pythonic!

**EDIT**

Here is my .i file that pipes gets and sets of the attribute itself to C++ getters and setters. I think this is what Nathan suggested in the comment below his answer.

```
%module test

%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_map.i"

namespace std {
    %template(StringIntMap) map<string, unsigned int>;
}

struct MyStruct 
{
    const std::map<std::string, unsigned int>& getData() const;
    void setData(const std::map<std::string, unsigned int>&);

    %pythoncode %{
        __swig_getmethods__["data"] = getData
        __swig_setmethods__["data"] = setData
        if _newclass:
            data = _swig_property(getData, setData)
    %}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're setting `struct.data`, it's expecting a `test.StringIntMap`, not a python `dict`.

The easiest thing is for you to do this:

```
struct.data = test.StringIntMap({ 'A':1, 'B':2 })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can confirm that your suggestion works. Do you know why SWIG does the implicit conversion from StringIntMap <-> dict for parameters to the setter method but not for the value of a field? I would expect the data= "method" to be more or less equivalent to the setData() method.

Comment: I think that it's basically because python and C++ have fundamentally different ideas about =.  In python the = operator simply overwrites the current value of something whereas in C++, you call operator= on that object.  std_map.i makes std::map behave as much like a dict as possible, but it doesn't make other objects do something fancy with setattr.  You could always subclass (or monkeypatch) struct add a property sett that will automatically do what you're asking for.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense more or less. Not familiar with the term monkeypatch, but I think that is what I ended up doing -- added an edit at the end of my post. Thanks for your help.